# Use the Squeeze Theorem to Prove $f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable at $c$ if $g(c)=g'(c)=0$ and $f$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Problem:

Suppose $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function and $g:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c \in I$. Assume that $g(c)=0$ and $g'(c)=0$. Prove that $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is differentiable at $c$ by using the definition of the derivative and the squeeze theorem. Note that $f$ need not be differentiable--so you cannot use the product rule.

---

Initial thoughts: Since $g'(c)=0$ and $g(c)=0$, it would make sense that $h'(c)=0$ if $f$ was differentiable at c. I'm assuming that $f$ being bounded some how makes this still work in the case $f'(c)$ DNE.

That said, I'm having a hard time figuring out where to start on this problem. Using the definition of the derivative I basically get the product rule:

$h'(c)=\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)g(x)-f(c)g(c)}{x-c}\\
=\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)g(x)-g(c)f(x)+g(c)f(x)-f(c)g(c)}{x-c}\\
=\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)[g(x)-g(c)]+g(c)[f(x)-f(c)]}{x-c}\\
=\lim_{x \to c}(f(x))\lim_{x \to c}(\frac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c})+g(c)\lim_{x \to c} (\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c})\\
=f(c)g'(c)+g(c)\lim_{x \to c} (\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c})\\$

Since $g'(c)=0$ and $f(x)$ is bounded, then

$f(c)g'(c) + g(c)\lim_{x \to c}(\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c})=g(c)\lim_{x \to c}(\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c})\\$

Since $f$ may not be differentiable at $c$, then $\lim_{x \to c}(\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c})$ may not exist. So I can see that the Squeeze theorem will help here. But I'm not sure how to use it.

Any hints on how to go about this would be most appreciated.

Comment: Note that you're not given that $f$ is continuous, only bounded.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: Because $f$ is bounded, there is some $M>0$ so that $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x$. Now $\left|\dfrac{f(x)g(x)-f(c)g(c)}{x-c}\right| = \left|\dfrac{f(x)g(x)}{x-c}\right| \le M\left|\dfrac{g(x)}{x-c}\right|$.

Comment: It's so obvious now! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You're most welcome. Also be careful about writing $\lim_{x\to c}$ too soon in such proofs. :) Oh, and welcome to MSE. I hope you learn a lot of mathematics!

Answer (score 2):

With the much appreciated hint from Ted, this is what I came up with:

Proof:

Suppose $f:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function and $g:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c \in I$ such that $g(c)=0$ and $g'(c)=0$. Let $h:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$.

Since $f$ is bounded, then there exists an $M \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

So $\left|\dfrac{h(x)-h(c)}{x-c}\right| =\left|\dfrac{f(x)g(x)-f(c)g(c)}{x-c}\right|
=\left|\dfrac{f(x)g(x)-0}{x-c}\right| 
=\left|\dfrac{f(x)g(x)}{x-c}\right| 
\le M\left|\dfrac{g(x)}{x-c}\right|
=M\left|\dfrac{g(x)-0}{x-c}\right|
=M\left|\dfrac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}\right|$

Thus $\left|\dfrac{h(x)-h(c)}{x-c}\right| \le M\left|\dfrac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}\right|$ and it follows that $-M\left|\dfrac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}\right| \le \dfrac{h(x)-h(c)}{x-c} \le M\left|\dfrac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}\right|$.

Since $\lim_{x \to c}(-M\left|\dfrac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}\right|)=-M|g'(c)|=0=M|g'(c)|=\lim_{x \to c}M\left|\dfrac{g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}\right|$, then, by the Squeeze theorem, $\lim_{x \to c}\dfrac{h(x)-h(c)}{x-c}=0$

Thus $\lim_{x \to c}\dfrac{h(x)-h(c)}{x-c}$ exists.

Hence, $h(x)$ is differentiable at $c$ and $h'(c)=0$.

Comment: This is correct. You have made perfect use of the hint given in the other answer. +1